# Change height of a swiped tableview cell on height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a standard tableview of .Subtitle style. However, I would like to show the detailed text only when the cell is swiped. I would like to increase the height of the swiped cell (and only the swiped cell) to display the detailed text. I have not tried creating 2 cell prototypes and swapping the cell on the swipe and I am not experienced enough to implement it. I could implement the optional function heightForRowAtIndexPath but that would change every cell unconditionally.

I would appreciate any ideas on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tableViewheightForRowAtIndexPath method, you could change specific cell height, and keep other cells in the same height.

you can check the below sample code

```
       NSIndexPath *selectedCellIndexPath;

        //

            - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewdidSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
                   selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath;

                   // Forces the table view to callheightForRowAtIndexPath
                [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArrayarrayWithObject:indexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; 
    }

            - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewheightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
                   // Note: Some operations like calling [tableViewcellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                   // will call heightForRow and thus create astack overflow
                   if(selectedCellIndexPath != nil
                         &amp;&amp; [selectedCellIndexPathcompare:indexPath] == NSOrderedSame)
                          return 64;

                   return 32; 
}
```